# Is egg white lysozyme different from bacterial lysozyme?

Tags: microbiology, enzymes

Someone told me that microbial lysozyme has effect on gram negative bacteria but egg white lysozyme only affect gram positive bacteria. Is it true?

Comment: Whoever knows the answer to this question knows it by (a) having done the necessary experiments, or (b) having read the reports of those who had done the necessary experiments. Start with 'b' and if you don't find any such reports, continue with 'a.'

Comment: I searched about documents to prove that but i can’t find any one

Comment: Search the PubMed literature database . . .

Answer (score 1):

[PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed) query: ["lysozyme"[Title]](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=%22lysozyme%22%5BTitle%5D) returns 8673 papers (many of which contain useful data about the activities of bacterial- and chicken-type lysozyme/muramidase against Gram-positive and Gram-negative bacteria).

For example, [Gajda & Bugla-Płoskońska (2014, Postepy Hig Med Dosw 21, 1501-1515)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25531714) write:

> **Lysozyme** (LZ, muramidase, N-acetylmuramylhydrolase) is a protein occuring in **animals, plants, bacteria and viruses.**
>
> **Lysozyme hydrolyzes** the β-1,4 glycosidic bonds between N-acetylmuramic acid (NAM) and N-acetylglucosamine (NAG) of **cell
>   wall** peptidoglycan (PG) **in Gram-positive and Gram-negative
>   bacteria.**
>
> In the **animal kingdom, three muramidase types** have been
>   identified: the c-type (chicken type), the g-type (goose-type) and the
>   i-type (invertebrates).
>
> **Muramidase shows bactericidal activity mainly against Gram-positive bacteria.** Cytolytic activity against cells of Gram-negative bacteria
>   has not been proved.

**Lysozyme** hydrolyzes bacterial cell walls, which is why its muramidase activity is **more effective against Gram-positive** than Gram-negative bacteria, for the former have **thicker cell walls.** Whether or not there is any difference in the effectiveness between the bacterial- and chicken-type lysozyme can be found in the papers; i have not read them.

But one of the 8673 papers is titled **Hen egg white lysozyme permeabilizes Escherichia coli outer and inner membranes** [(Derde et al., 2013, J Agric Food Chem. 16: 9922-9929)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24047287).

The quick-and-dirty **answer** to the question, *is it true that bacterial lysozyme affects Gram-negative bacteria but hen-egg (chicken-type) lysozyme only affects Gram-positive bacteria?* is: **No.**

The 'slow-and-clean' answer can be found in those 8673 papers.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I already found this answer but i need to know the difference of the two type of lysozyme: a. Microbial lysozyme b. Egg white lysozyme on their effect on bacteria (is microbial lysozyme affect gram negative bacteria and egg lysozyme doesn’t ?

Comment: @MahmoudOraby i edited my answer; you have everything you need to find the answer for yourself; or you can wait until someone else gives you a more detailed and comprehensive answer.

Comment: @MahmoudOraby if you read 100 abstracts of "lysozyme" papers a day---which is doable---you will become lysozyme expert in 3 months (if that's what you would like to be). Of course, you can narrow your PubMed "lysozyme" search using logical operators (*and*, *or*) and additional keywords, and filter the results by publication type (e.g., *Review*)---this way you can get to the bottom of the pit faster . . .

Comment: already I began to do that